# Is there a way to read the command line parameters from a library?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get the equivalent of `string[] args` in a library several layers down from the main exe.  Is there anyway to do this?  I don't see anything obviuos.

Comment: This kind of dependency makes for a bad library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Comment: But be aware that the first item will be the running process, these can differ in order from what gets passed into `main(string[] args) { }`

Comment: @Clint How can the order be different?  It's quite important that the order be exactly what the user entered.

Comment: args[0] will be the path to the startup exe. The rest will be in the right order!

Comment: @Servy I've had them come out in a funky order before but that could have been down to any number of external factors (passing through pieces of the codebase for example), but yes, apart from the first he should be fine, but it's always best to check.

Answer (score 3):

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```